# Handling message in Netty

Tags: java, netty

I'm new to Netty and need to handle a message in a custom way. I have the following interfaces:

```
public interface Command{ }

public interface CommandFactory{
    Command(byte b)
}

public interface CommandProcessor{
    void process(Command c, Object arg)
}
```

Now I receive some data from client and want to process it. I'm implementing `ReplayingDecoder<Void>` for that:

```
public class CommandDecoder extends ReplayingDecoder<Void>{
    private CommandFactory cmf;
    private CommandProcessor cmp;

   void decode(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, ByteBuf in, List<AnyRef> out){
       Command command = cmf.command (
         in.readByte()
       );

       String arg = new String (
         in.readBytes (
           in.readShort()
         ).array()
       );

      cmp.process(command, arg); //<------------ Here
  }
}
```

The thing is I'm not sure about it. I process the command inside a decoder. It looks strange to say the least. Maybe I should pass the decoded `commmand` and the `arg` further to `channel pipeline`.

But which `ChannelInboundHandler` to choose for the command processing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right. It would be better to split the decoder and the actual business logic for command processing. The best Handler, in that case, would be `SimpleChannelInboundHandler`. In general, it does nothing but accepts the message of the specific type.

It may look like this:

```
public class MyCommandHandler extends SimpleChannelInboundHandler<Command> {

    @Override
    protected void channelRead0(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Command command) throws Exception {
         //process here your message
         //command.type;
         //command.args  
    }

}
```

So after you decoded your command:

```
Command command = cmf.command (
         in.readByte(),
         new String (in.readBytes (in.readShort()).array())
       );
```

You may pass it to the next `MyCommandHandler` in the pipeline with:

```
out.add(command);
```